# How to create/move multiple objects on a 2d array at once?

Tags: java, arrays, object, console, 2d

We are trying to create a shape and place it on a 2d console based board. The shapes will be made up of multiple points on a 2d array. So a triangle for example would look like this is the user input 4x3x3...

```
   1
 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

The shapes will be able to move and grow/shrink. We have the shapes able to display their dimensions already, as well as the board itself made. But actually putting them on the board and moving them (all the points as a whole) is proving to be difficult. Any suggestions? Here is our code so far...

Board code...

```
public class Board {

private int size;

public Board(int boardSize){
    this.size = boardSize;
}

public String toString() {

    Playable[][] grid = new Playable [getSize()][getSize()];

    int k = 1;
    while (k <= (grid.length+2)) {
        System.out.print('-');
        k++;
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (Playable[] row : grid) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (Playable item : row) {
            System.out.print((item == null ? " " : item));
        } System.out.print("| \n");
    }

    k = 1;
    while (k <= (grid.length+2)) {
        System.out.print('-');
        k++;
    }
    return "";
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}
 }
```

Shape Code...

```
 public class Rectangle extends Quads implements Playable {

public Rectangle(int numberOfSides, int numberOfDimensions) {
    super(4, 2);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public double calcPerimeter() {
    return ((this.getDimensions()[0] + this.getDimensions()[1]) * 2);
}

public double calcArea() {
    double area;
    area = this.getDimensions()[0] * this.getDimensions()[1];
    return area;
}

public String showDimensions() {
    String display = "";
    display += "For this " + this.getColor() + " "
            + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": \n";

    display += this.getDIMENSION_LABELS()[0] + ": "
            + this.getDimensions()[0] + "\n";
    display += this.getDIMENSION_LABELS()[1] + ": "
            + this.getDimensions()[1] + "\n";
    display += this.getDIMENSION_LABELS()[2] + ": "
            + this.getDimensions()[0] + "\n";
    display += this.getDIMENSION_LABELS()[3] + ": "
            + this.getDimensions()[1] + "\n";
    display += "The perimeter is " + this.calcPerimeter() + ", \n";
    display += "The area is " + this.calcArea() + ", \n";
    display += "And the seniority is " + this.getSeniority() + "\n";
    return display;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define new grid each time you print it make `Playable[][] grid` as field so you can store state then do like this

```
grid[0][0] = new Playable(){...};//create
grid[1][0] = grid[0][0];//copy to new location
grid[0][0] = null; //remove from old location
```

Comment: What would you expect in the create (Playable) body? I get what you are doing here but not sure on what it is you would expect me to do exactly.

Comment: I've done Playable anonymous just to let you know that there should be some implementation. You already have Rectangle and Quads so I think You'd expect more implementations of that interface.